# Finding intersection entries in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I've run into an R-programming problem that I can't seem to wrap my head around.  I have data like the following:

```
data = data.frame("start"=c(1,2,4,5),
                  "length"=c(2,2,2,3),
                  "decision"=c("yes","no","yes","yes"))
```

Which looks like:

```
  start length decision
1     1      2      yes
2     2      2       no
3     4      2      yes
4     5      3      yes
```

Row one stands for a sequence of integers that start at 1 for length 2 (1,2).  Row 3 is 2 integers starting at 4 (4,5).  I'm looking for intersections between entries that have a 'yes' decision variable.  When the decision variable is 'no', then the sequence is thrown out.  Here's what I've attempted so far.

I think I need to create a sequence list first.

```
sequence.list = lapply(seq(dim(data)[1]),
                       function(d){
                         seq(data$start[d],(data$start[d]+data$length[d]-1),by=1)
                         })
```

This outputs:

```
sequence.list
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 4 5

[[4]]
[1] 5 6 7
```

Which is a start.  Then I create a list that counts intersections between items on my list (I stole this idea from another post on here).

```
count.intersect = lapply(sequence.list,function(a) {
  sapply(seq(length(sequence.list)), 
         function(b) length(intersect(sequence.list[[b]], a)))
  })
```

This creates the list:

```
 count.intersect
[[1]]
[1] 2 1 0 0

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 0 0

[[3]]
[1] 0 0 2 1

[[4]]
[1] 0 0 1 3
```

The way to read this is that entry 1 in the data frame has 2 trivial intersections with itself and 1 intersection with entry 2.

Here's where I get fuzzy on what to do.  Make it a matrix?

```
intersect.matrix = do.call(rbind,count.intersect)
```

Then set the rows and columns of non-used entries to zero?

```
intersect.matrix[,data$decision=="no"]=0
intersect.matrix[data$decision=="no",]=0

intersect.matrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    2    1
[4,]    0    0    1    3
```

Now, I would like to return indices 3 and 4 somehow.  I want to find the rows (or columns) containing non zeros that are also not on the diagonal.

Sorry for posting the whole procedure, I also want to know if there is a shorter way to go from the starting dataframe to finding intersections in used entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not interested in non zero values on the diagonal, first I would subtract them away:

```
diag.mat <- diag(intersect.matrix) * diag(ncol(intersect.matrix)
```

which gives:

```
intersect.matrix - diag.mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    1
[4,]    0    0    1    0
```

Then identify which of the columns still hold non zero entries using `which`:

```
which(colSums(intersect.matrix - diag.mat) != 0)
[1] 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked whether there is a short way to go from your data frame `data` to the indices. Here it is.

(Note: This may be hard to understand if you're new to R.)

1) Create the sequence list:

```
sequence.list <- apply(data[1:2], 1, function(x) seq_len(x[2]) + x[1] - 1)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2 3
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 4 5
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 5 6 7
```

2) Count intersects and create the intersect matrix

```
intersect.matrix <- outer(s <- seq_along(sequence.list), s, 
                          Vectorize(function(a, b) 
                            length(Reduce(intersect, sequence.list[seq(a, b)]))))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    2    1    0    0
# [2,]    1    2    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    2    1
# [4,]    0    0    1    3
```

3) Set cells corresponding to `"no"` to zero

```
idx <- data$decision == "no"
intersect.matrix[idx, ] <- intersect.matrix[ , idx] <- 0
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    2    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    2    1
# [4,]    0    0    1    3
```

4) Find indices of non-zero rows/columns (except diagonal)

```
result <- which(as.logical(colSums("diag<-"(intersect.matrix, 0))))
# [1] 3 4
```

Comment: @nfmcclure Right. I corrected it and also omitted the `which` in the line above.